# How can i solve this node_modules problem?

Tags: javascript, npm

[what is this?how can I solve this? I uninstalled node_modules also tried yarn but no result. There is no error in my code][1]

```
`{
"name": "resume-builder-client",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@emailjs/browser": "^3.6.2",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"animate.css": "^4.1.1",
"daisyui": "^2.20.0",
"firebase": "^9.9.1",
"randomcolor": "^0.6.2",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-animated-text-content": "^1.0.1",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-firebase-hooks": "^5.0.3",
"react-hook-form": "^7.34.0",
"react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
"react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"react-simple-chatbot": "^0.6.1",
"react-toastify": "^9.0.7",
"react-tsparticles": "^2.1.4",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
 },
```

`

package.json file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHQij.png

Comment: Could you give more information, for example how is your package.json file, if you already tried npm i to reinstall the modules?

Comment: Don't post screenshots when cut-and-paste of the text will suffice: see [ask].

Comment: **package.json**

Answer (score 0):

Please add your package.json into the question.

Based on the error message "Please verify that the package.json has a valid 'main' entry", I'm guessing you need to add the "main" attribute in your package.json.

Like this:

```
"main": "./lib/index.js",
```

This is what NPM says about that attribute:

> The main field is a module ID that is the primary entry point to your
> program. That is, if your package is named foo, and a user installs
> it, and then does require("foo"), then your main module's exports
> object will be returned.
>
> This should be a module relative to the root of your package folder.
>
> For most modules, it makes the most sense to have a main script and
> often not much else.
>
> If main is not set it defaults to index.js in the packages root
> folder.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#main

Comment: You beat me on time. Hope it will helps anyway

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually a problem with nome_modules package, instead try this:
In your package.json file, in the root folder will be there something like this:

```
     "name": "MiniDeckBuilder",
     "version": "0.0.1",
```

Check the name of the first file that starts when you run the App, and add the name to the package.json like this: (should be app.js or index.js)

```
     "name": "MiniDeckBuilder",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "main": "nameToReplace.js",   //<--- Add this line replacing the name
```